# Does the inverse of a matrix have the same condition number as the matrix?

Tags: matrices

I couldn't find any answer how to explain whether $A$ matrix and $A^{-1}$ have the same condition number or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition number of an invertible matrix $A$ is $\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ and so the condition number of $A^{-1}$ is $\|A^{-1}\|\|(A^{-1})^{-1}\| = \|A^{-1}\|\|A\|$. Hence, $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have the same condition number.

Comment: Isn't that only true (with the generally accepted meaning of the condition number of a matrix) if $\|A\|$ is the spectral norm of $A$? Maybe, you should mention that in your answer.

Comment: The definition of condition number in my answer applies to any consistent matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ and is not restricted to the spectral norm.

Comment: Okay, you are right. The statement **includes** that one for the condition number on the basis of the spectral norm which is AFAIK the most often used one for estimating the sensitivity of numerical algorithms for matrices.